# change template_path for devise mailer instead of default devise mailer views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, mailer

When using Devise to create custom model `User`.  The views are created via `$ rails g devise:views users`
How to tell Devise to use templates in `views/users/mailer` when sending confirmation emails to user??

Answer (score 2):

step 1, uncomment the "config.mailer" line and rename `Devise::Mailer` to your own Mailer Class

```
# config/initializers/devise.rb

# Configure the class responsible to send e-mails.
# config.mailer = 'Devise::Mailer'
config.mailer = 'CustomMailer'
```

step 2,  create a new file with `CustomMailer` class which inherits from `Devise::Mailer`.  Then override method `headers_for` to set `template_path` to the folder with customized `Devise` views

```
# app/mailers/my_mailer.rb
class CustomMailer < Devise::Mailer
  def headers_for(action, opts)
    super.merge!({template_path: 'users/mailer'}) # app/views/users/mailer
  end
end
```

Comment: Starting from Rails 7 you need to be aware that including `config.mailer = 'CustomMailer' needs this custom-mailer (and also Devise mailer) to be required in Devise initializer first as well. Related Q&A here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72308475/1677069