# After upgrading Rails from 6.1.1 to 7.0.3 my Devise mailers can't be initialized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, actionmailer, ruby-on-rails-7, rails-upgrade

I started upgrading my application from Rails 6.1.1 to 7.0.3. While doing this I also had to upgrade Devise from `4.7.3` to `4.8.1`.

With old setup everything worked fine. Now after upgrading I can't start none of the following:

1. rails server
2. rails console
3. rspec specs
4. rake rails:update

They all fail with the following error message:

```
/home/andres/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@my_app/gems/activesupport-7.0.3/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:280:in `constantize': uninitialized constant AccountMailer
Did you mean?  ActionMailer (NameError)
    from /home/andres/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@my_app/gems/activesupport-7.0.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:74:in `constantize'
    from /home/andres/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@my_app/gems/devise-4.8.1/lib/devise.rb:320:in `get'
    from /home/andres/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@my_app/gems/devise-4.8.1/lib/devise.rb:343:in `mailer'
    from /home/andres/apps/my_app/config/initializers/devise.rb:25:in `block in <main>'
    from /home/andres/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@my_app/gems/devise-4.8.1/lib/devise.rb:307:in `setup'
    from /home/andres/apps/my_app/config/initializers/devise.rb:5:in `<main>'
    from /home/andres/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@my_app/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in `load'
    from /home/andres/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@my_app/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in `load'
    from /home/andres/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@my_app/gems/railties-7.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:667:in `block in load_config_initializer'
    from /home/andres/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@my_app/gems/activesupport-7.0.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:208:in `instrument'
    from /home/andres/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@my_app/gems/railties-7.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:666:in `load_config_initializer'
    from /home/andres/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@my_app/gems/railties-7.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:620:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
    from /home/andres/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@my_app/gems/railties-7.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:619:in `each'
    from /home/andres/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@my_app/gems/railties-7.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:619:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    from /home/andres/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@my_app/gems/railties-7.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
    from /home/andres/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@my_app/gems/railties-7.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
    from /home/andres/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@my_app/gems/railties-7.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /home/andres/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /home/andres/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/andres/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:422:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /home/andres/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /home/andres/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:421:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /home/andres/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@my_app/gems/railties-7.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `each'
    from /home/andres/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@my_app/gems/railties-7.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `tsort_each_child'
    from /home/andres/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:415:in `call'
    from /home/andres/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:415:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /home/andres/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/andres/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
    from /home/andres/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
    from /home/andres/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/andres/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
    from /home/andres/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    from /home/andres/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@my_app/gems/railties-7.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
    from /home/andres/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@my_app/gems/railties-7.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:372:in `initialize!'
    from /home/andres/apps/my_app/config/environment.rb:7:in `<main>'
    from /home/andres/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@my_app/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
    from /home/andres/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@my_app/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
    from /home/andres/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@my_app/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:35:in `require'
    from /home/andres/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@my_app/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/application.rb:106:in `preload'
    from /home/andres/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@my_app/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/application.rb:157:in `serve'
    from /home/andres/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@my_app/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/application.rb:145:in `block in run'
    from /home/andres/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@my_app/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/application.rb:139:in `loop'
    from /home/andres/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@my_app/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/application.rb:139:in `run'
    from /home/andres/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@my_app/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:/home/andres/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
    from <internal:/home/andres/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

### Mailer files

I'm having the following mailer-folder structure:

```
app/mailers:

account_mailer.rb
application_mailer.rb
```

My account_mailer.rb has the following declaration:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

# using SendGrid's Ruby Library
# https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-ruby
require 'sendgrid-ruby'

class AccountMailer < Devise::Mailer
  include SendGrid
  default template_path: 'devise/mailer'
```

Based on that the `constantize` method should be able to do all it needs to I understand (file names match the class name, files are present under correct folder structure).

### Devise initialization with mailer

My custom `AccountMailer` is initialized inside Devise initializer like this: `config.mailer = 'AccountMailer'`.

As I said- this all worked like a charm in Rails 6.1.1 but now I can't get my head around what's wrong after the Rails upgrade.

### What I've tried:

I commented out **all** the `AccountMailer` references. After that I started getting errors about Devise::Mailer like this (in RSpec):

```
An error occurred while loading rails_helper.
Failure/Error: require File.expand_path('../config/environment', __dir__)

NameError:
  uninitialized constant Devise::Mailer
  Did you mean?  Devise::Mailers
# /home/andres/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@vaab/gems/activesupport-7.0.3/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:280:in `constantize'
# /home/andres/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@vaab/gems/activesupport-7.0.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:74:in `constantize'
# /home/andres/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@vaab/gems/devise-4.8.1/lib/devise.rb:320:in `get'
# /home/andres/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@vaab/gems/devise-4.8.1/lib/devise.rb:343:in `mailer'
# ./config/initializers/devise.rb:25:in `block in <main>'
# /home/andres/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@vaab/gems/devise-4.8.1/lib/devise.rb:307:in `setup'
# ./config/initializers/devise.rb:5:in `<main>'
# /home/andres/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@vaab/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in `load'
# /home/andres/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@vaab/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in `load'
# /home/andres/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@vaab/gems/railties-7.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:667:in `block in load_config_initializer'
# /home/andres/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@vaab/gems/activesupport-7.0.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:208:in `instrument'
# /home/andres/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@vaab/gems/railties-7.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:666:in `load_config_initializer'
# /home/andres/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@vaab/gems/railties-7.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:620:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
# /home/andres/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@vaab/gems/railties-7.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:619:in `each'
# /home/andres/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@vaab/gems/railties-7.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:619:in `block in <class:Engine>'
# /home/andres/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@vaab/gems/railties-7.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
# /home/andres/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@vaab/gems/railties-7.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
# /home/andres/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@vaab/gems/railties-7.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
# /home/andres/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@vaab/gems/railties-7.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `each'
# /home/andres/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@vaab/gems/railties-7.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `tsort_each_child'
# /home/andres/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@vaab/gems/railties-7.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
# /home/andres/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@vaab/gems/railties-7.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:372:in `initialize!'
# ./config/environment.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
# ./spec/rails_helper.rb:8:in `require'
# ./spec/rails_helper.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
```

When I commented out **all** the Devise mailer configuration lines in Devise initializer like this:

```
# config.mailer = 'AccountMailer'
# config.mailer.perform_deliveries = !Rails.env.test?
# config.mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
```

Then only at that point my application seemed to work 100% as it needs to.

I checked the [Devise changelog](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md) for releases after 4.7.3 that I was upgrading from and I didn't notice any relevant changes there.

I also checked Rails mailer related configuration changes between versions 6.1.1 and 7.0.3 from [release notes](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/7_0_release_notes.html) and I again didn't notice anything that might affect.

The `constantize` method that appears in error trace is described here: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-constantize

I'm taking the Rails upgrade tutorial as basis from [here](https://www.fastruby.io/blog/rails/upgrades/upgrade-rails-6-1-to-7-0.html).
What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After setting the class name, the getter `config.mailer` in the next line constantizes, because it needs the class object.

In Rails 6.0 and 6.1, that access got a noisy warning, autoloading a reloadable class during boot got deprecated. In Rails 7, the deprecation cycle finished, and autoloading a reloadable class or module during boot is an error condition.

One possible solution is to preload that mailer with a `require` call in the initializer for Devise. The autoloader will see `AccountMailer` was already loaded, and will ignore `account_mailer.rb`.

The rationale is that `AccountMailer` cannot be reloadable, because reloaded changes would have no effect, since on reload that initializer does not run. This error prevents introducing this incongruence without noticing.

Comment: Golden! Thank you @xavier-noria ! Seems I got too used to some warnings and missed them. Only things I had to include to fix this were the lines `require 'devise/mailer'` and `require 'account_mailer'` in the top of my `config/initializers/devise.rb`. **NB! They have to be exactly in that order as my custom mailer depends first on Devise-mailer.** And of course I added a beefy comment on top of my custom mailer to warn that this code will not get autoloaded since it's loaded during the Rails boot in Devise initializer.